# Providing environment variables with vuejs and azuredevops

Tags: vue.js, azure-devops

Right now I am building a project and using vuejs for the front end. When testing locally, creating a .env.developement and .env.production work fine when in different environments and will show variables correctly. My issue now comes when building in azure devops. I am pointing to the dist folder and this is, obviously, only providing production variables which makes sense.

Is there a way to pass in dev vs prod environment variables to vuejs to build against in a azure devops/vue project?

Seems like there is something "magical" about the way vue is injecting these files into the index.html file and I cant pinpoint how vue is deciding which env variables to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me a question not related with Azure DevOps Pipelines but with Vue compile process.

I don't know a thing about Vue, but if it works similarly to other javascript /typescript frameworks, you should specify the environment in your build tasks.

In my Angular projects I may create a npm task specifying which environment to choose (i.e. **npm run build:prod** or **npm run build:pre**). And then, in my Azure Pipelines run the right task depending on the environment I'm going to deploy (you may even store the output in different build artifacts depending on the environment, so you'll have all those artifacts available in your deployment pipeline).

Finally (just a recommendation) I would recommend you to review which values you store in your .env.production file, just to be sure that it's safe to store that file in a repository. If you have some sensitive information, I'd recommend you to use Pipeline Variables instead. Pipeline Variables may be keep hidden, available only for the DevOps Team.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! yeah just needed to add a a script to the package.json to run the mode in build or prod